# Devices in OS X Internet Sharing can't see each other

Tags: network, wifi, internet-sharing

I really like the feature of OS X to share it's Ethernet connection over WiFi to other devices. But it appears that those devices are unable to "see" each other (e.g. you can't play a LAN game with two iDevices). I ensured that my firewall is disabled and that IP forwarding is enabled (`sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1` and `sysctl -w net.inet.ip.fw.enable=1`). Still, no possibility for those two devices to connect.
Is it unnecessary to enable IP forwarding? Is there a possibility to enable this behaviour?

Comment: struggling with same issue... so far no solution :-(